# calculate traffic speed for multiple concurrent threads

Tags: java, android

I am looking for an efficient way to calculate the traffic speed for my app.  I have multiple concurrent threads downloading data over the network.  I have a facade that collects how many bytes they have read via a call to facade.setCurrentData(int data)

Now, every second I grab the currentData field to calculate the speed for the particular second.  so this will do the math to figure out the speed and then reset the currentData field to 0.  Of course all this runs synchronized, along with the setCurrentData method, which leads me to believe this is not very efficient as the download threads need to wait to aquire lock before posting the total speed.  Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: ever considered using AtomicLong/Integer, they have an `addAndGet` method that concurrently adds a value to a long/integer variable. You wouldn not need to use `synchronized`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

Your only options are to:

- Keep it as it is, synchronization isn't very costly on a fast machine anyway
- Use AtomicLong/Integer as chahuistle mentioned
- Keep track of the last read value, store it, then take the difference when reading the next time, eliminating the need for synchronization and you will only need to make "currentData" volatile.

Comment: but i will need to reset it back to 0 after calculating for the current second

Comment: Then your only options are to use AtomicLong/Integer as chahuistle said, or not reset it to 0 but keep track of the last read value and then take the difference.